# Integral of matrix simple $\int (X-YW)^T (X-YW) dY$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Suppose that $X$ is a vector of $(1 \times k)$, $W$ is a matrix of $m \times k$ and $Y$  a vector of $1 \times m$. The variable $a$ in this case can be seen as a constant number.

I'm currently stuck at integrating: $\int_0^1 (X- a -YW)^T (X -a-YW) dY$

I'm not sure if my answer is correct: $(X-a)^2 - (X-a)W^T + \frac{1}{3}W^2$ where I basically follow the derivation from normal scalar calculus. I'm not sure how to do it in 2-D or tensor calculus.

Please enlighten me on the integration, perhaps:

- Show the derivation of the integral
- If you think I'm missing a lot of matrix/vector integral, can point out to me the formula. I've search all day long for a good tutorial in higher dimension calculus as well but no luck.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Two things to consider: 1) what is the index $i$ representing ( you don't use in anywhere, could this be a carryover from a more detailed problem?). 2) What is the definition of $\int_0^1 dZ$ ? $Z$ has $m$ coordinates, so are you  calculating a multiple integral $dZ_1\cdots dZ_m$ or what? I think that once you clarify these points the question will make more sense.

Comment: I added the update in my questions and some clarification there. Please take a glance if these has clarify your doubts. In addition to that, should I reframe my question without the index?

Comment: Btw, $Z_i$ is a vector of $1 \times m$ and the matrix $Z = [Z_1, Z_2, ... Z_n]$ is a matrix which contains $n$ observations, each observation is described by $m$ features.

Comment: Sorry, things are still not clear. You seem to be saying that $Z$ is a $1\times m$ vector AND also a scalar $Z\sim U[0,1]$. If $Z$ is a $m$ dimensional vector, please explain what $dZ$ is . Is it a volume integral? If so, what is the range? Is it a $[0,1]^m$ sized cube?

Comment: Hi I think you misunderstood, forget about the indices. Let me rephrase the problem then. For your information previously,  $Z$ is not a volume integral. It's not even valid to integrate over $Z$ in my context :)

Answer (score 0):

Well this is my answer based on just assummption that calculus in vector/matrix is same as in scalar $(X-a)^2 - (X-a)W^T + \frac{1}{3}W^2$. I know it's not a correct assumption but I'm still confused how to do calculus in vector, matrix, or even tensor.

My steps is as follows:

\begin{align}
&= \int_0^1\left\{(X - a -WY)^T (X_i - a -WY) \right\}dY\\
&= \int_0^1\left\{(X - a -WY)^2\right\}dY\\
&= (X-a)^2 - \int_0^12(X-a)W^TYdY + \int_0^1W^2Z_i^2dY\\
&= (X-a)^2 - (X-a)W^T + \frac{1}{3}W^2\\
\end{align}

But I'm afraid the dimension of the above three terms in my final answer doesn't add up. $(X-a)^2$ has dimension $1\times k$ (I guess this is element wise square then?), $(X-a)W^T$ has dimension $1 \times k$ but $\frac{1}{3}W^2$ has dimension $m \times k$ which is different. (I also guess this square term will end up as element wise square?).